# How to fix 'OSStatus' is ambiguous without more context when using VTCompressionSessionEncodeFrame

Tags: swift, xcode, compression, video-toolbox

I have been trying to use `VTCompressionSessionEncodeFrame` to encode some CMSampleBuffers, but when I try to use it I always get this error: `Expression type 'OSStatus' (aka 'Int32') is ambiguous without more context`

I have tried to find out what it is but with no success, here is the code I am using:

`var compressed = VTCompressionSessionEncodeFrame(session: vtCompressionSession, imageBuffer: imageBuff!, presentationTimeStamp: nil, duration: CMTime.invalid, frameProperties: nil, infoFlagsOut: infoFlags)`

I do not reference the variable compressed anywhere else in the code as well.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: did you `Import VideoToolbox`?

Comment: Yes, I did import it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I changed

```
var compressed = VTCompressionSessionEncodeFrame(session: vtCompressionSession, imageBuffer: imageBuff!, presentationTimeStamp: nil, duration: CMTime.invalid, frameProperties: nil, infoFlagsOut: infoFlags)
```

to

```
var output: VRCompressionOutputHandler? = nil
VTCompressionSessionEncodeFrame(session: vtCompressionSession, imageBuffer: imageBuff!, presentationTimeStamp: nil, duration: CMTime.invalid, frameProperties: nil, infoFlagsOut: infoFlags, outputHandler: output)
```